# Groupby and Filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 1 |
| foo | 0 |
| foo | 1 |
| bar | 0 |
| bar | 0 |
| bar | 0 |

I want to keep rows that contain a 1 in column `B` and delete rows that have a 0 **if there is a 1 in the same group**. If there is no 1 in the group I want to keep all zeros.

So that my df looks like this in the end:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 1 |
| foo | 1 |
| bar | 0 |
| bar | 0 |
| bar | 0 |

I tried:

```
grouped = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: (x['B'] == 1).any())
```

but it does not work, it keeps only the `foo` entries (and all of them).

Comment: You may want to mention that you are talking about Pandas dataframes and not about regular Python objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sum` to mark those groups that have non-zero elements, then apply boolean indexing

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum')
df[(df['sum'] == 0) | (df['B']==1)].drop(columns = 'sum')
```

produces

```
    A   B
0   foo 1
2   foo 1
3   bar 0
4   bar 0
5   bar 0
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit different approach:

```
>>> df[(df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum').eq(0)) | df.B]
      A  B
0  foo   1
2  foo   1
3  bar   0
4  bar   0
5  bar   0
```